# Problem with my subdomain with .htaccess root as subdir

Tags: domains, htaccess, url

I am working on a site making my subdir to appear as root just like
`//example.com/` is `//example.com/subdir` and also access/load files hiding the subdir. My site have this `.htaccess` (below) and its working.

My problem is when I add a subdomain like `//admin.example.com| which is`//example.com/subdir/admin`my`.htaccess`redirects me to the main domain`//example.com`

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/  [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ example/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* example/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* example/index.php?rp=$0 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll need to do something along these lines:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

#Match admin.example.com default page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ example/admin/index.html [L]

#Match files that exist in example/admin/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}example/admin/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* example/admin/$0 [L]

#Match non-exisiting files in example/admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* example/admin/index.html?rp=$0 [QSA]

#Redirect anything that's not example.com or admin.example.com to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/   [L,R=301]
#Match example.com default page
RewriteRule ^$ example/index.html [L]

#Match files that exist in example/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}example%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* example/$0 [L]

#Match non-exisiting files in example
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* example/index.html?rp=$0 [QSA]
```